# How to have tabBar animate in after the view is fully pushed into view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, show-hide

I am trying to emulate the way TweetBot/NetBot animates the tabBar in after a push from the tableView of Accounts action. When the view is fully pushed, only then does the taBar animate in from the bottom. I have tried all sorts of hide/show methods and all seem to fail when it comes to the "show" part.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I presume you are not using a UITabViewController since it cannot be pushed into a UINavigationController stack, so I think you are using a standalone UITabBar embedded in a UIViewController. Is this assumption right?

Try with this code (I didn't try it).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];

    // Calls showTabBar method after SOME_DELAY. You can also call directly [self showTabBar] if you want zero delay.
    [self performSelector:@selector(showTabBar) afterDelay:SOME_DELAY];
}

- (void)showTabBar {
   // Before the animation begins, your UITabBar must be outside the view controller's view frame. 
   CGRect tabBarFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                   CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds), 
                                   CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),
                                   CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame);
   self.tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame;

   // Let's start with the animation, setting a new frame for tab bar inside an animation block
   [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
       // Change origin Y. It assumes that the height of self.tabBar is right, otherwise put the height you want instead of CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame).
       tabBarFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame); 

       self.tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame;
   }];
}
```

Comment: OK, I *was* using a NavController -> TabBarController before your answer. Since the Storyboard let me do it, and it all worked, I assumed it was OK.  Are you saying I need to use a normal VC and just roll my own Tabbarcontroller? I can animate th tabbar out of view just fine, but showing it afterward is pretty messaed up if working at all.

Comment: [Documentation](http://bit.ly/hUDRwc) about UINavigationController states that:

`pushViewController:animated:` _"This object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller"_

`initWithRootViewController:` _"This object cannot be an instance of the UITabBarController class."_

Anyway, maybe pushing it could work, but I don't know if that could cause some misbehavior. 
Are you sure you really need to push it in a nav stack? Maybe you could achieve the same result just hiding the tabbar when needed.

Have you tried my code for the animation, btw?

Comment: Decided to go a different direction until I can figure this out. Thanks for trying to help Alessandro :)